# How to redirect java.util.logging to a file?

Tags: java, file, redirect, java.util.logging

I have a java program using an external library. The main program uses `log4j` to log its messages and the library uses `java.util.logging`.

My problem is that log messages from the external library and the main program are mixed in the console.

I would like to redirect **all** log messages from the external library to a file. I tried to do that with a `logging.properties` file:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = foo.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter
```

This file is initialized with:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "logging.properties");
```

Unfortunately, log messages from the external library keep appearing in the console.
Should I use something like `slf4j` to intercept log messages from `java.util.logging`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751736/how-to-get-java-logger-output-to-file-by-default

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some code from one of my programs.  This also does automatic rotation.  The config class is my own that's read from a properties files.  You can just replace that with your own values.

```
Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger(""); 
logHandler = new FileHandler(config.getLogFile(), 
                             config.getLogRotateSize()*1024*1024, 
                             config.getLogRotateCount(), false); 
logHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter()); 
logHandler.setLevel(Level.INFO); 
rootLogger.removeHandler(rootLogger.getHandlers()[0]); 
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO); 
rootLogger.addHandler(logHandler);
```

Note this is for a stand-alone program.  Any application server has it's own logging configuration tools.  The program can also change the formatter and levels on the fly if a dynamic debug mode is desired.